How to access csv file in my scrapy spider in zyte scrapy cloud?
I need to parse my CSV file data to do some specific job. On my system, I am successfully reading the CSV file but when I deploy to the Zyte server then I get the error that the file is not found.
Here is my code structure:
account_history/
├── account_history/
│   ├── spiders/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── ...
├── data/
│   └── results.csv
├── scrapy.cfg
├── requirements.txt
├── scrapinghub.yml
└── setup.py

Here is my scrapy spider that part of code where I am accessing file.
import scrapy
import re
import pandas as pd
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import os
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageMethod

class AddressesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "addresses"
    allowed_domains = ["www.domain.com"]

    def start_requests(self):

        current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        chunk_size = 1000 
        csv_file = os.path.join(current_dir, '..', '..', 'data', 'results.csv') 

Here is setup.py code:
# Automatically created by: shub deploy

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name         = 'project',
    version      = '1.0',
    packages     = find_packages(),
    entry_points = {'scrapy': ['settings = account_history.settings']},
)


Your setup.py indeed doesn't include your CSV in your package.
